# How do I see internal WebRTC logs in firefox?

Tags: logging, firefox, webrtc

I tried setting these environment variables

`MOZ_LOG=signaling:timestamp,sync,5,mtransport:5,webrtc_trace:5`
`MOZ_LOG_FILE=/my/path/here.log`

It did not work. and then,

`R_LOG_DESTINATION=stderr R_LOG_LEVEL=3 R_LOG_VERBOSE=1`

It did not work either.

Tried using the logging feature in about:webrtc by addding log file in about:config. It did not work too.

Also tried the logging feature from about:networking. It did not work either.

Tried setting security.sandbox.content.level to 0. No difference.

I tried all the above steps in both stable firefox and nightly builds.

What am I missing?

OS : Windows 11
Browser: Firefox 106.0.5
Firefox 108.0a.1(Nightly)

Comment: Note that there is a typo in the `MOZ_LOG` setting shown here: it should be `sync:5`, not `sync,5`. This makes the whole `MOZ_LOG` setting be ignored.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. This is a typo I made here. I typed the command in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this as well. The following worked for me:

1. Start firefox with `MOZ_LOG` flags including `webrtc_trace:5`:

   ```
   MOZ_LOG=webrtc_trace:5  /usr/local/firefox/firefox-bin
   ```
2. In `about:webrtc`, click "Start Debug Mode".

This was enough to get WebRTC logs written to stderr. It seems *both* steps are necessary.